# Why do dynamically allocated pointer arrays not need dereferencing to get to their actual members

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation, dereference

So I recently came across the following piece of code:

```
struct Student
{
    int *number;
    char *name;
    double *marks;
};

int main(){
    int n;
    Student *s;
    s = new Student;
    cout << "Enter the number of subjects the student learns: ";
    cin >> n;
    s->number= new int;
    s->name=new char[20];
    s->marks=new double[n];
    cout << "Enter the name of the student: ";
    cin >> s->name;
    cout << "Enter the number in class of " << s->name << ": ";
    cin >> *(s->number);
    for (int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++){
        cout << "Enter mark No" << i+1 << " of the student: ";
        cin >> s->marks[i];
    }
}
```

When I worked with one dimensional arrays of pointers there was the need to use dereference twice. Once to reach the n-th pointer of the array ("s->marks[i]" in this case) and a second time to get the actual value that is pointed which I thought meant to write it like this:

```
*(s->marks[i])
```

This is apparently not needed, although I thought this would return the memory serial number contained by the pointer "marks[i]". On the other hand, there is the need to dereference the "number" pointer that is a single variable like that:

```
*(s->number)
```

This I perfectly understand.

Can someone please explain to me (or point me to a good article) why there is no need to use the dereference operator when working with dynamically allocated pointer arrays like, in this case, "marks". I am also confused with the use of the "name" char array pointer which is used rather like a normal char variable.

Thanks in advance for all the help.
Edit to sum up:
I just now realised that

```
/*the following two statements declare an array of pointers hence allow for the
use of double dereference*/
int* marks[n]; //static memory allocation
int** marks=new int*[n]; //dynamic memory allocation

/*the following two statements declare an array of variables hence allow for the
use of only one dereference (just a simple 1 dimensional array)*/
int marks[n]; //static memory allocation
int* marks=new int[n]; //dynamic memory allocation
```

I thought that I was dealing with something similar to the first pair of statements. In reality, I had to deal with the second pair.

Comment: It would perhaps be easier to understand if the `Student` object weren't needlessly allocated dynamically. This is code is bad, don't take it as an example of how things are done.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`s->marks` is a pointer to the first element of an array of `double`.

`s->marks + i` is a pointer to the `i`th element.

`*(s->marks + i)` dereferences that to give the `double` element itself.

`s->marks[i]` is a convenient way to write `*(s->marks + i)`. It includes the dereference operation, so there's no need for another one.

Comment: yeah but marks is an array of pointers so what I thought is that 
    s->marks[i] would return a pointer and not a double variable

Comment: @AdamPayne: No, it's a pointer to (the first element of) an array of `double`. A pointer to an array of pointers would look like `double**`.

Comment: @AdamPayne `marks` is not an array, it is just a single pointer to `double`. It is made to point to a dynamically allocated array of `double`.

Answer (score 1):

Let assume that you have

```
int x = 10;
int *p = &x;
```

then expression

```
*p = 20;
```

is equivalent to expression

```
p[0] = 20;
```

Relative to your code you could write

```
cin >> s->number[0];
```

instead of

```
cin >> *(s->number);
```

The same way you could write

```
cin >> *( s->marks + i );
```

instead of

```
cin >> s->marks[i];
```

According to the C++ Standard

> The expression E1[E2] is identical (by definition) to *((E1)+(E2))

Again returning to your code expression

```
cin >> *(s->number);
```

can be written as

```
cin >> *(s->number + 0);
```

that is

```
cin >> s->number[0];
```